# Multiple FilterExpression in dynamodb scan

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

Im trying to build a histogram of a certain attribute in my dynamodb.
I thought the easiest way would be to use multiple `filter-expression`
This is my baseline query with a single `filter-expression` and it works

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name test --select "COUNT" --filter-expression "contains(score, :s)" --expression-attribute-values '{ ":s": { "N": "1" } }' --limit 100
```

Now, im trying to extend it to multiple `filter expressions` and im not sure how.
I have tried:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name test --select "COUNT" --filter-expression "score = :s" --filter-expression "score = :s1" --expression-attribute-values '{ ":s": { "N": "1" }, ":s1": { "N": "40" } }' --limit 100
```

and

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name test --select "COUNT" --filter-expression "score = :s" | "score = :s1" --expression-attribute-values '{ ":s": { "N": "1" }, ":s1": { "N": "40" } }' --limit 100
```

Answer (score 22):

Probably I am late to answer. But, was searching for a similar scenario and got nothing. Still answering if someone else could benefit.

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name test --select "COUNT" \
--filter-expression "score = :s OR score = :s1" \
--expression-attribute-values '{ ":s": { "N": "1" }, ":s1": { "N": "40" } }' \
--limit 100
```

Comment: How could you write the attribute in that `--filter-expression` is the name had `:` on it? For instance, instead using `score` use `custom:attribute`?

Answer (score 6):

Filter expressions are a kind of condition expression. You can [combine filter expressions with boolean logic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Syntax). However, in your example, you can get away without using AND/OR operators to combine expressions.

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name test --select "COUNT" \
--filter-expression "score IN :s, :s1" \
--expression-attribute-values '{ ":s": { "N": "1" }, ":s1": { "N": "40" } }' \
--limit 100
```

Comment: This is what is returned after running the query as presented: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: ":s", near: "IN :s,"

Comment: needs parentheses? `score IN (:s, :s1)`

Answer (score 1):

using **between**

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name test --select "COUNT"  \
--filter-expression "(score between :s and :s1)"  \
--expression-attribute-values '{ ":s": { "N": "0" }, ":s1": { "N": "10" } }'
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are searching for the `nodeJs` filter Expression:

```js
const params = {
        TableName: "orderMessages",
        Key: {
            order_id,
            
        },
        FilterExpression: "#order_id = :ordrId OR #timestamp < :ts",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#order_id": "order_id",
            "#timestamp": "timestamp"
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":ordrId": order_id,
            ":ts": now
          },
    }
```

Happy coding :)